# Xampp installer Error

Tags: debian, software-installation, xampp

I tried to install xampp ver 5.5.24 on Debian using terminal, after setting it to run as executables in permissions with.

```
./xampp-linux-5.5.24-0-installer.run
```

I get

```
Segmentation fault
```

Then I tried to use sudo

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-5.5.24-0-installer.run
```

and nothing happens. no error but installer did not open.
What could be the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer should really be a comment but here it goes.

Just to be sure, did you follow the install instructions per the [FAQ](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html)? Do you have an `/opt/lampp` directory after running with `sudo`? I don't think you will but it's worth a look.

If you don't have the directory mentioned above then you can try running the installer with the `--mode text` option. This may work for you like it did for another user with a [similar issue](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=57981).

Comment: The installation procedure is still the same. On the link 'similar issue' says file not found.

Comment: Roger that, just had wanted to be sure. I also fixed the second link by removing my accidental double-pasted url.